# Monitor progress of dd.DataFrame.apply

Tags: dataframe, parallel-processing, progress-bar, monitoring, dask

How can I monitor the progress of a row-wise Dask DataFrame apply operation?

Wrapping the line with `ProgressBar()` doesn't seem to do anything, i.e. nothing is printed on the console?

```
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
with ProgressBar():
    df_calc = ddf.apply(myfunc, axis=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Dask operations are lazy by default.  Computation only happens when you call `compute` or `persist`.

```
df = dd.read_csv(...)        # This lazily builds up a computation
df = df[df.name == 'alice']  # This lazily builds up a computation
result = df.amount.sum()     # This lazily builds up a computation
result = result.compute()    # This triggers actual work
```